# opencart 2.2 cart update warning

Tags: opencart

In my opencart 2.2 cart, pressing quantity update give the warning: " The information you have entered on this page will be sent over an insecure connection and could be read by a third party. Are you sure you want to send this information?" --- then drops the customer in never, never land. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using 'https' url ?

Comment: yes - and there is a global redirect provided by my hosting company of http to https.

Comment: Check whether all internal links in your website are https.